# Extracting hashtags from user input

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have been asking similar questions before so this may be taken down but I feel like the code I have now should work but it doesn't.

```
String post [] = new String [100];
System.out.println("\nType your post");
String userPost = input.nextLine();
post[0] = userPost;
                  
String hashtags ="";
for (int i = 0; i<post.length && post[i]!=null;i++){
    String[]words = post[i].split(" ");
    for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
        if(words[j].trim().startsWith("#")){
            hashtags+=words[j].trim() + " ";
        }
    }
}
if(hashtags.trim().isEmpty())
    System.out.println("No hashtags were typed");
else 
    System.out.println("Hashtags found: " + hashtags );
```

I feel like this should work but when running this code, it skips asking for user input and immediately prints No hashtags were typed.

Comment: Why can the `post` array hold 100 strings if you only ever set the first position of the array? What do you think your program does if the user wants to input a post that consists of multiple lines? Have you tested it with an input that begins that includes `#`? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Hi. Welcome. Please read the help on how to ask a question.  Also you've made an important point, probably without intending. Debugging is _exactly_ the process of getting rid of the difference between what you feel or think your code should be doing and what it actually does.  You'll never learn how to do this by asking for the right answer on SO. Rather ask to learn how to correct your incorrect ideas and feelings after you've explained your best effort to do this yourself.

Comment: what is the input you are providing to this programme?

Answer (score 0):

What should you do is to use regular expression Java API, extracting all searched hashtags from the provided String variable with the proper regexp:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class HashtagsFinder {

public static void main() {
    String input = "#HASHTAGS #HASHTAG #ANOTHER_HASHTAG BUT#THISISNOTAHASHTAG";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\B#\\w+").matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

A regular expression passed as the `Pattern.compile()` argument matches expressions in line with the following rules:

1. `\B` - ensure that there is no word boundary at the beginning.
2. `#` - ensure that there is exactly one hash char at the beginning of the word - with the previous part, it ensures that the hash char is always at the beginning of the word.
3. `\w+` - match one or more of the possible word character (alphanumeric and undescore), so we won't be collecting expressions with just the hash char.

Output of the code pasted above:

```
#HASHTAGS
#HASHTAG
#ANOTHER_HASHTAG
```

What is also important - instead of the standard `java.util.regex` package, you should use https://github.com/google/re2j, since it's faster and provides safer compliation (standard Java regular expressions library uses backtracking to compile passed regex, which may cause our program to exceed available stack space).

Comment: How do I make the string input be something the user types in?

Comment: Exactly as you are doing it above - declare Scanner instance for stdin, then read next line from the input to the String variable with the nextLine() method.